Can the ham technician test be set up so a volunteer examiner can read it to the test taker who cannot read well?
My relative has wanted his ham license for many many years. However, he cannot read well.
Can the test be set up so a volunteer examiner can read it to him?

You might want to add where you're from. I guess the US, but rules will probably vary by country. And I wouldn't expect much judgement here, it's a rather friendly place...

According to https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/14521/testing-blind-license-applicants there are options for blind people. You might want to give the test center a call to see if they are willing to use the same setup for your husband.

The arrangements are specifically for the blind, but this seems like a perfectly reasonable accommodation.
I would strongly recommend contacting the local ham club (who typically have the Volunteer Examiners who will oversee the exam) and ask them if they can accommodate him. I can imagine there is fear and embarrassment, but my experience is that ham clubs are very accepting with very little judgement.

Fully agree. I've been a VE for a bit (pre-Covid) and think most VEs would be more than happy to make it work and very happy to welcome a new licensee. It would probably require a more private test since reading the questions aloud would bother other test takers.
